# set path for java app

Tags: java, path

Im running FreeBSD (a jail inside FreeNAS)

I have this jar file that I execute with this command:

```
/usr/local/bin/java -jar /dir1/file1.jar -d -u root
```

If I execute it when I am inside /dir1 , everything works.
If I execute it from any other folder, the file1.jar starts loading, but it fails with:

```
plugins/lib folder not found, file1 may not be able to start...
```

That "plugins/lib" is a directory inside /dir1 so I am assuming my.jar files needs it and I have to add some path on my environment or call my .jar some other way.
How can I add this path?

Comment: Depends on what there code is actually doing. If it's trying to load resources then those resources need to be on the class path.

Comment: How do I add a path to that class path on freeBSD?

Comment: If you're running with java -jar the resource directory will need to be contained in the jar or in the jar manifest. Assuming you're loading classpath resources, which is hard to say, because you provide little actionable information.